# Rules - Send mail to all addresses in email field of specific content type

Tags: rules, tokens

I have a content type (school) with an unlimited email field (field_email).
Now on creation of another node (page), I would like to send to all emails stored in the "field_email" of all school nodes an email.

I started by created a rule with the "rules" module but i cannot figure out how to pull the data from a separated node (school).

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Want to try programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Views Rules](https://drupal.org/project/views_rules) module. For achieve this goal first you have to create a view to get all mail values of content type (school) and than its result provide to rules using this module. For more information go through the documentation of Views Rules module.